# How do I add a string to an arraylist if the string is two or more words long?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string, arraylist

How do I add a string to an arraylist if the string is two or more words long?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your song name: ");
        Track_name.add(in.next());
        System.out.println("Song name added ✅");
```

If i use this then it adds two strings to the array. I want to be able to add two words as one string.

Comment: `nextLine()` should work?

Answer (score 2):

`nextLine()` takes the whole line entered:

```
Track_name.add(in.nextLine());
```